# convergence of geometric mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{w_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence of positive real numbers such that $w=\text{sup}\{w_n\}$. Suppose the subsequence $\{w_{n_{i}}\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ of the sequence $\{w_n\}$ convergence to zero then does this implies that the geometric mean $(w_0w_1\cdots w_n)^{1/n}$ converges to zero?

I am not sure how to partition the set $(w_0w_1\cdots w_n)^{1/n}$ to check the convergence. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question is currently phrased, it doesn't imply that the geometric mean goes to $0$. Consider the following sequence

$$1/2, 2, 1/4, 2, 2, 1/8, 2,2,2, 1/16, 2,2,2,2, \ldots$$

The sequence is the sequence $1/2^k$ with $k$ $2$s in between $1/2^k$ and $1/2^{k+1}$.

This sequence is bounded, and has a subsequence that goes to $0$. Namely, $1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, \ldots$.

However, if we group $1/2^k$ with the $k$ $2$s that follow it, then these multiply out to $1$. Hence, every so often, the geometric mean of the sequence will be equal to $1$.

---

However, let us consider the case, when $w_i$ converges to $0$ instead of only having a subsequence that converges to $0$. Then by the AM-GM inequality, we have that the geometric mean is bounded by the arithmetic mean.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a $N$ such that for all $i > N$ we have that $w_i < \epsilon$. Thus, we have that for all $n > N$.

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{w_i}{n} \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^N (w_i) + \epsilon. $$

Taking the limit of $n$ to infinity, we see that the arithmetic mean is at most $\epsilon$. Since this is true for arbitrary positive $\epsilon$, we that arithmetic mean (and hence the geometric mean) goes to $0$.

Comment: can we get the same conclusion if the supremum of the sequence is less than or equal to 1 since then it is not possible to put counterweights for cancellation for the subsequence converging to 0.

Comment: My concern is with the power of $1/n$. You could pad the sequence with enough $1$'s that the $1/n$th power now makes it big. If the supremum was strictly smaller than 1, then maybe, but even then I don't think the subsequence condition is strong enough.